# NODEJS EXPRESS : redirect data post to get

Tags: node.js, express

I am a bit new in nodejs, and i am trying to post a form and if the form is ok i redirect to one of my .get, but i would like to forward data and use it in the .get.

i followed the docs and redirect only take status/url but not data so i tried this:

```
req.session.message = 'Erreur lors de la sauvegarde';
req.session.errors = errors;
res.redirect('/profil');
```

and in my method get

```
data.message = req.session.message;
data.errors = req.session.errors;
req.session.message = null;
req.session.errors = null;
```

Btw its not the good way but its working fine. How can i simplify this code ?

Thanks for your help,
Best regards

Comment: I don't see a whole lot wrong with your setup. You could formalize it a bit by using [`connect-flash`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) or something similar, but that pretty much does the same as what you're doing now.

Comment: Ok i see i checked and finally i found connect-flash and it does the same thing as mine. Maybe it is a bit cleaner. Thanks for your help